# Python script to maskchange first three SSN number

Tags: python-3.x

Looking for help in writing python script to change first three numbers in a SSN.

Input from a txt file containing sample SSN numbers (ssn_ori.txt).
Output to a new txt file

Ex: convert `123-44-9898` to `246-44-9898` (add +1 to first, +2 to second, +3 to third). 2 digit will only keep first digit (12 -> 2)

Comment: What happens is you have the number 469-44-9898? What should happen with the third digit, 9, when adding 3?

Comment: @A Magoon, for each digit, if number more than 9 then use the first digit only (12 to 2, 13 to 3 etc.). thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest implementation I can think of is:

```
t = '123-44-9898'

def evaluate_ssn(ssn):
    first = str(int(ssn[0]) + 1)[-1]
    second = str(int(ssn[1]) + 2)[-1]
    third = str(int(ssn[2]) + 3)[-1]

    return first + second + third + ssn[3::]

evaluate_ssn(t) #246-44-9898
```

<s>Keep in mind that there are a few potential problems with this code. Such as what happens when a modified number adds to greater than 9? Since this wasn't specified in the question I did not address them in my answer.</s>

Comment: @ Magoon, Is it simple to add a function/feature, so if addition of numbers is more than 9, then it should be either be 0 or first digit (ex: 12 becomes 2)

Comment: @scorpionz: See my updated answer below (that you accepted and un-accepted because it was just adding 1 to all digits, now fixed and does what you want). In the meantime, upvoting Magoon answer as it is simple, does not address your problem (that was not specified) but clearly states that it does not so +1

Comment: @scorpionz - I updated my answer to include the functionality you asked about.

Comment: @ A Magoon - Thank You so Much!

Answer (score 0):

Because the question has fixed pattern (3-2-4 digitals). We could have a straight forward solution. 
Convert the first three digitals into int and add 123, then convert back to string, and concatenate with the rest of the test string.

test = "123-44-9898"
str(int(test[0:3]) + 123) + test[3:]

If you have more complicated cases, you could always try to use regular expression. https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html

Answer (score 0):

with a regex + replacement function: if number is >10 then wraps up to number%10, all in a nice list comp.

```
import re

def do_repl(m):
   return "".join([str((int(x)+(1+i))%10) for i,x in enumerate(m.groups())])


r=re.compile(r"(\d)(\d)(\d)(?=-\d+-\d+)")
test = "123-44-9898"

print(r.sub(do_repl,test))

test = "929-44-9898"

print(r.sub(do_repl,test))
```

output:

```
246-44-9898
042-44-9898
```